# ipAddressResolutionFailed error with mongo, docker and perfectSwift

Tags: swift, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I'm getting this error:

> Fatal error: Error raised at top level:
>   MongoSocket.MongoSocket.Error.ipAddressResolutionFailed: file
>   /home/buildnode/jenkins/workspace/oss-swift-4.2-package-linux-ubuntu-16_04/swift/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift,
>   line 191

when building my docker-compose.
The docker-compose file looks like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
    nginx:
      build: ./docker-nginx-amplify/
      environment:
        - API_KEY=apikey
        - AMPLIFY_IMAGENAME=myapp-Squad
        - mode=production
      ports:
        - "80:80"
        - "443:443"
    myapp-mongo:
      image: mongo:3.2.21
      ports:
        - "57017:27017"
      volumes:
        - ./database/myapp-mongo:/data/db
    myapp-perfect-api:
      build: ./factory-api-perfect-swift/
      ports:
        - "5500:6600"
      links:
        - myapp-mongo
```

In my swift app, the connexion to the mongodb is established like so:

```
let myDatabase = try MongoKitten.Database("mongodb://myapp-mongo/taleo")

if myDatabase.server.isConnected {
    print("[SERVER MONGODB] Connected on \(myDatabase.server)")
} else {
    print("[SERVER MONGODB] CONNECTION FAILED !")
}
```

Neither docker-compose ps nor docker-compose images shows nothing despite the fact that all the docker-compose command seem to be executed successfully.

What I'm I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried adding the mongo port, like `mongodb://myapp-mongo:27017/taleo`?

Comment: Yes. I just tried and got the same error